# what event(place) should i use for change culture and calendar in mulilanguage web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture, global.asa

i have a multi language web site...
i made two folders in visual studio for languages(en + my language)and made my web site for each one!
for one language web site i had a class for changing culture and calendar to my culture and callled that class in Global.asax like below :

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myLanCultureAndCalendar.SetCultureAndCalendar();
}
```

but for multi language web site what can i do about that class ?
mean where should i call that class for each languages?
`my pages are base on master and content pages`

as you know `global.asax Application_BeginRequest runs First -> after that we have content page_Load -> and at last Master page_Load`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to implement that  class in Application_BeginRequest   event ...like this..

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String language = Request.UserLanguages[0];
    if (language.Length > 1) language = language.Substring(0, 2);
    .......
    ........

}
```

I suggest you pls go through this link for [more info](http://forums.asp.net/t/969928.aspx)

I hope it will helps you..

Comment: thanks for answer / but is there another way without using UserLanguages?

Comment: any other idea ? it seems it's not good to use user's machine languages for this issue / can we use session or something like that?